# Riding bicycle without using seat

Tags: seatpost, bmx

I've almost always rode on a BMX, so I've never been sitting while riding because of how low the seat is.Now I've had a chance to try out a more normal bike but I found sitting on the seat to be very uncomfortable so I've been riding several km standing.

I've also tried many different seats but they were all too uncomfortable.

I'm quite concerned that if I start doing this everyday Ill develop some leg problems (like blood circulation maybe?) or have other issues.

Comment: Define what you mean by "normal bike".  Is it a road bike, mountain bike, hybrid bike, dutch bike, or some other style?  I'm not sure if you'll experience many problems, but standing is much less efficient than sitting.  You'll be able to go much further and get less tired if you can find a seat/bike combination that is comfortable to you.

Comment: I recall a broad race in mountainous conditions about 20 years back where somehow one of the riders had her seat disassemble itself midway through the ride.  So she rode a 20-30 mile stage standing up, until the next rest stop when the seat was replaced by her crew.  Did pretty well, IIRC.  (But I can ride all of about 20 feet standing.)

Comment: @Kibbee mountain bike (the large version BMX is a mountain bike too)

Comment: A mountain bike should be comfortable with a decent seat.  Is the saddle at the right height?  Your knee should be slightly bent when your pedal is at the lowest position.  You should NOT be able to touch both fee flat on the ground when you are on the seat.  That kind of placement is fine for children and people just learning to ride, but it is not a very optimal position.

Comment: Oops -- make that "road race" above.

Comment: Find a good local bike shop that has a "try it out" seat program. You may have some luck with this at triathlon stores as well. A properly fitting seat is critical. Also, as the other poster has said, getting used to a bike seat takes some adaptation.

Comment: What do you mean by uncomfortable? Is it just a strange feeling or is it pain? I've felt pain at the pelvis from sitting 2hrs on a hard and narrow seat.

Comment: Cindy Whitehead - Sierra 7500!!!

Answer (score 2):

Traveling long distances on a bike seat is almost always going to be uncomfortable when your body isn't used to it. Give it time.

But also, consider taking your bike with you to have a professional make sure the seat and the bike fit you. Some people have managed to permanently damage their blood vessels ( I won't go into detail ) by improperly sitting on a bike seat. Call around to see if there's a bike shop near you that can help and ask how much they'll charge you.

Comment: I like this answer.But should I worry about possible leg problems?

Comment: @BMX I'd be more worried about my back than legs. There is a chance you could develop some knee problems if you get a muscular imbalance in the tights but squats once a week would keep you right

Comment: @Will Will doing pistol (one legged) squats work too/better?

Comment: @BMX - What hillsons is describing is very long term type damage. It is still good to have a properly fitting bike and seat, but nerve/blood vessel damage takes years to become permanent (Unless you have a trauma of some sort, such as crash or bad impact), and muscle imbalances will also take months to a year to develop to a point where you have to do supplemental exercises to correct them.